# I want to use an HTML page in my grails app. But Not able to

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.0.1 and i tried linking to the html page using  with the direct url="somefile.html> but it is not working out . How do i do it ?please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Make sure the file is stored under `web-app/somefile.html`, this is where you store raw files for the server.
2. Instead of using a hard-coded URL, use the `g.resource()` method or the `<g:resource>` tag.  In these cases, you'll use it like so:

   ```
   <a href="${g.resource(file:'somefile.html')}">My Link</a>
   ```

The reason to use the `g.resource` tag is it guarantees a correct link to the file.  If you just hard code the file like `href="somefile.html"`, then is is a relative path.  If you are at the URI `myapp/controller/action/foo`, it will look for the file under `myapp/controller/action/somefile.html`.

Note: If you are using the `cached-resources` plugin or something similar, you will find the output URL is not actually `myapp/somefile.html`.  The file is still accessible from that location, but the generated links will point to a static URL instead.